# Asymmetric encryption method in dotnetnuke

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, dotnetnuke

**Asymmetric encryption** solves the trust problem inherent in symmetric encryption by using two different keys: a public key for encrypting messages, and a private key for decrypting messages. This makes it possible to communicate in secrecy with people you don't fully trust. **RSA** is a cryptosystem for public-key encryption, and is widely used for securing sensitive data.

I checked the dotnetnuke source but I don't know dotnetnuke uses RSA for asymmetric encryption or not?

It would be very helpful if someone could explain asymmetric encryption method in dotnetnuke.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetNuke doesn't use any asymmetric cryptography by itself. It uses some hash functions like MD5 (bad) and SHA-256 as well as symmetric encryption like two-key 3DES (very bad) and AES.

The only thing is that you [can configure](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/release/8.0.4/Documentation/Using%20the%20Control%20Panel/Host%20Console/Site%20Management/Setting%20SSL%20Settings%20for%20a%20Single%20Site.html) to use transport security (SSL/TLS) which includes various types of asymmetric cryptography. In SSL/TLS, client and server can negotiate a cipher suite depending on both their capabilities. You need a private key and a certificate (which contains the signed public key) in order for the connection between client and server to be encrypted.